# How to bind certain kernel threads to a given core?

Tags: linux, multithreading, performance, process, linux-kernel

I have a number of kernel threads that I want to get off of a given core for performance reasons. Some of these I am able to move using taskset however there are others I cannot.

In particular I see processes like migration, watchdog, rcuc, etc. that do not respond to my attempt to rebind them.

For example, if I try to rebind the watchdog process, I get the following:

```
# taskset -pc 0 207
pid 207's current affinity list: 0
sched_setaffinity: Invalid argument
failed to set pid 207's affinity.
```

How can I get these off of the cores so I can properly isolate them for performance reasons?

I suspect these processes are interfering with my full dynticks mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several kernel threads are tied to a specific core, in order to effect capabilities needed by the SMP infrastructure, such as synchronization, interrupt handling and so on. The `kworker`, `migration` and `ksoftirqd` threads, for example, usually have one instance per virtual processor (e.g. 8 threads on a 4-core 8-thread CPU).

You cannot (and should not be able to) move those threads - without them that processor would not be fully usable by the system any more.

Why *exactly* do you want to move those threads anyway?

Comment: I suspect they are interfering with the full dynticks mode in my kernel 3.10. I have only 1 other process running on the core, I have tickless mode enabled in my kernel build, I have rcu callbacks on different threads but it's still not working. I'm guessing it's the kernel threads.

Comment: @NathanDoromal: can you define "not working"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well with full dynticks enabled I expect that only one local timer interrupt with fire per second if my process is the only thing running on that core. However when I run my process with affinities set on the core the local timer interrupt continues to fire 1000 times a second.

Comment: @NathanDoromal: and how does that affect your process? Is there a specific problem that you are trying to solve, or just a matter of curiosity?

Comment: I have a 16 core CPU and I'm using the top 8 cores for a high performance virtual machine. I am running realtime tasks and I'm doing everything I can to reduce latency and stutters. So far I am successfully isolating those cores from userland processes (using cpuset), but kernel threads and interrupts are still being processed on them. I can see some activity spikes on the cores even before I've launched my VM. Is there nothing more I can do to stop my host system from using these cores while my VM is running?